# Apex Specialist Challenge 1 too Many DML Rows

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code

I'm Working through this challenge and appear to have run into an issue i have not found a solution to (nor does it appear that anyone has posted a question on this specifically.)

looking at the log is pretty painful as any System.debug() lines appear to be dropped due to the size of the log being >18MB  but it appears there are 40000 rows to be added.  Having caved and looked at some of the other code dumps out there i dont see that anyone else looks to have had this issue or made any special arrangements with batching  and as far as i can see i haven't done anything drastically different to them (but the subtlety is clearly more than enough to cause an issue).

So if anyone could have a look over this and give me a **hint as to where/why** i have gone wrong it would be a great help. I'm not looking for a link to a *working* code set to copy i'm hoping for some understanding as to where my approach is incorrect/causing issues

With my trigger

```
trigger MaintenanceRequest on Case ( after update) {    

List<Case> closedCases = new List<Case>();
for (Case c : Trigger.New){

    System.debug('Type :' + c.Type );
    System.debug('Equals Repair: ' +c.Type.equalsIgnoreCase('Repair'));
    System.debug('Equals Routine Maintenance: ' +c.Type.equalsIgnoreCase('Routine Maintenance'));

    if (
        (c.Type.equalsIgnoreCase('Repair') || c.Type.equalsIgnoreCase('Routine Maintenance')) 
        && c.isClosed == true )
        {
        closedCases.add(c);
    }
}
System.debug(closedCases.size() + ' cases were closed');

if(closedCases.size() > 0){
    MaintenanceRequestHelper.createScheduledMaintainance(closedCases);
}
```

}

and helper

```
public with sharing class MaintenanceRequestHelper {
public MaintenanceRequestHelper() {

}


public static Map<Id,Integer> getMainainanceCycleForCases(){
    List<AggregateResult> maintainTimes = [SELECT Maintenance_Request__c, MIN(Equipment__r.Maintenance_Cycle__c)cycle
                                            FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
                                            GROUP BY Maintenance_Request__c 
                                            ];
    System.debug(maintainTimes);
    Map<Id,Integer> maintinTimeMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();

    for(   AggregateResult  e :  maintainTimes ){
        maintinTimeMap.put((Id)e.get('Maintenance_Request__c'), ((Double)e.get('cycle')).intValue());
    }

    System.debug(maintinTimeMap);

    return maintinTimeMap;
}

public static Map<Id,List<Id>> getMaintainanceItems(List<Case> closedCases){
    // map maintainance_Request_ID, Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
    List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> equipmentMaintainanceList = [SELECT Maintenance_Request__c,
                                                    Equipment__r.Id 
                                            FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
                                            Where Maintenance_Request__c IN :closedCases];


    Map<Id,List<Id>> maintainance_equipmentMap = new Map<Id, List<Id>>();

    for (Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c e:equipmentMaintainanceList){
        System.debug('Putting : '+ e.Maintenance_Request__c + ' : ' + e.Equipment__r.Id);
        if(maintainance_equipmentMap.containsKey(e.Maintenance_Request__c)){
            maintainance_equipmentMap.get(e.Maintenance_Request__c).add(e.Equipment__r.Id);
        }else{
            maintainance_equipmentMap.put(e.Maintenance_Request__c,new List<id>{e.Equipment__r.Id});
        }
        System.debug('Map now : '+ maintainance_equipmentMap);
    }

    System.debug('Returning: ' +maintainance_equipmentMap);

    return maintainance_equipmentMap;
}



public static void createScheduledMaintainance(List<Case> closedCaseList) {
    System.debug(closedCaseList.size() + ' Cases to create');

    Map<Id,Integer> maintainTimeMap = getMainainanceCycleForCases();
    Map<Id,List<Id>> maintainanceItems = getMaintainanceItems(closedCaseList);   // map maintainance_Request_ID, Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c

    List<Case> createNewCases = new List<Case>();
    
    for(Case c : closedCaseList){
        Case newCase = new Case();
        newCase.Type = 'Routine Maintenance';
        newCase.Status = 'New';
        newCase.Vehicle__c = c.Vehicle__c;
        newCase.Subject = c.Subject;
        newCase.Date_Reported__c = Date.today();
        newCase.Date_Due__c = Date.today() + maintainTimeMap.get(c.Id);
        newCase.ProductId = c.ProductId;

        createNewCases.add(newCase);
    }

    System.debug(createNewCases.size() +' to insert');
    list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> itemsListToinsert= new list<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>();

    if(createNewCases.size()>0){
        insert createNewCases;
  

        for(Case ca : createNewCases){
            
        
            for(Id key: maintainanceItems.keySet()){
                List<Id> equipment = maintainanceItems.get(key);
                for (Id e : equipment){
                    Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newitem = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
                        newitem.Equipment__c=e;
                        newitem.Maintenance_Request__c= ca.Id;
                        itemsListToinsert.add(newitem);
                }
            }
        
        }

    }

    System.debug('itemsListToinsert Size: ' +itemsListToinsert.size());
    if (itemsListToinsert.size() >0){
        insert itemsListToinsert; //<<<< ERROR TRIGGERS HERE and has ~40000 rows <<<<<
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

So, It seems i was over complicating the issue to an extent.

Having taken a break and walking through the problem again something just didnt sit right with this block of code.

```
if(createNewCases.size()>0){
    insert createNewCases;


    for(Case ca : createNewCases){
        
    
        for(Id key: maintainanceItems.keySet()){
            List<Id> equipment = maintainanceItems.get(key);
            for (Id e : equipment){
                Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c newitem = new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c();
                    newitem.Equipment__c=e;
                    newitem.Maintenance_Request__c= ca.Id;
                    itemsListToinsert.add(newitem);
            }
        }
    
    }

}
```

For -> For -> For -> create new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c

With 0 checks to see if this new Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c was needed.

I ended up partly re-writing the class but the main change was re-working the section of code above to

```
List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> equipmentMaintainanceList = [SELECT Maintenance_Request__c,
                                                                            Equipment__r.Id 
                                                                    FROM Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c
                                                                    Where Maintenance_Request__c IN :closedCaseList];


        List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c> updatedEquipment = new List<Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c>();
        for(Case closed : closedCaseList){
            for(Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c eqip : equipmentMaintainanceList){

                if (eqip.Maintenance_Request__c == closed.Id){
                    Equipment_Maintenance_Item__c e = eqip.clone(false, false, false, false);
                    e.Maintenance_Request__c = oldToNewMap.get(closed.Id).Id;
                    updatedEquipment.add(e);
                }
            }
        }

        if (updatedEquipment.size() > 0 ){
            insert updatedEquipment;
        }
```

For me the lesson is be very mindful of nested for loops when the outcome is going to come up against some hard and fast governor limits.